# Trying to hide this text that shows up after "pause" in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

This text "Press any key to continue", I don't want this to show up, is there a way I could hide this part of the text but I also want the previous to stay, thus the `pause` command.

Comment: Thank you all, both methods worked, both answers were helpful. However, since I'm more familiar with the "pause" code approach, I will continue to use SvW's method. Kudos to you Zoredache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
pause > nul:
```

`nul:` is the DOS/Win equivalent to `/dev/null`, redirecting the output to nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

Use `set /p garbage=`.  Your program will wait until you hit enter, and nothing will be displayed.  The garbage variable will contain anything they typed.  You can safely ignore that.

Comment: There's a minor difference - `pause` will accept any key, while `set /p` will wait for a line feed (enter key).